# Sending ID of post using Jquery

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax, variables

I have a while loop in php that fetches assoc result of a query and then displays them in a class with an id of the user who made that post, im trying to send the id of the class to php as am i sending the num variable however i seem to be getting an undefined index error when trying to send it.

This is what i have so far -

```
(".eventer button[name=lol]").click(function() {
    console.log('clicked');
    var ida = this.id;
    thisBtn = $(this);
    parent = $(this).parent();
    num = parent.data('num');
    id = parent.data('id');
    if (typeof num != 'number') {
        num = 0;
        $(this).attr('disabled', true);
        $.post('javas.php?ida= ' + ida, {
            num: (num + 1),
            id: id
        }, function(data) {
            console.log('Ajax success');
            parent.next('.status').html(data);
            thisBtn.attr('disabled', false); // reset  });
            console.log('Ajax success');
            parent.data('num', ++num);
            parent.next('.status').html(data);
            thisBtn.attr('disabled', false); // reset 
        });
    });

console.log('-- end');
```

Any help is appreciated thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Should you be using:

```
.attr('id');
```

instead of:

```
.data('id');
```

Comment: i dont think thats the problem

Comment: Can you show us the html, the only issue I can see in the js is the data('id') ?